# What attitudes toward Jesus are acceptable for a Jew?

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy, historical-figures, christianity

What attitudes toward Jesus are acceptable for a Jew? I understand that idolatry, or embracing the mainstream Christian perception of Jesus as divine, is absolutely out of the question. Furthermore, there are strong textual and cultural reasons that Jews should not consider Jesus to be Moshiach. However, is it acceptable to revere or even love Jesus? To appreciate his teachings to any degree? To consider him righteous, a tzaddik, or a good person?

(Please note: I am not asking "Was Jesus actually righteous/a tzaddik/worthy of reverence by a Jew?" But since that question will inevitably encroach on mine, I would like to mention that the "New Testament" contains wildly disparate reports of what Jesus actually taught during his lifetime. Whereas some gospelists portray Jesus as rejecting halacha, other accounts, including his most famous sermon, quote him as insisting categorically that halachic observance must be maintained in its entirety. What Christians actually did with that information is, I think, irrelevant to this question.)

Comment: Although I did not read Kosher Jesus by controversial rabbi Schmuley Botech, it may provide some answers. Let me suggest SAH, that you read information from the Internet with caution. In my experience, many sites, including come-and-h### and talmudreve###, tend to be anti-Jewish and hardly reflect Jewish thought on Jesus.     http://www.timesofisrael.com/im-an-apostle-to-non-jews-rabbi-shmuley-on-kosher-jesus/

Comment: Basically, this question is that if we change information, or select what we think is real, and come to the conclusion that he was righteous, may we actually think so. Keep in mind that he is irrelevant to Judaism. There is no prescribed law of what to think of him. Just like I may have whatever opinion I want about Homer, yeshu, once he becomes anonymous and is getting a new description may be anything between a saint and most evil.

Comment: @HaLeiVi Thanks for this valuable comment. I would wonder to a certain extent whether laws such as ahavas yisroel and loshon hara would apply to him. But I guess it's impossible to determine.

Comment: So I heard about a gemara in which 3 people -- maybe Titus Harasha, Balaam, and one definitely JC -- are asked by Onkelos about the Jews. JC tells Onkelos to love the Jews and seek their good or something. The other two say quite differently.

Comment: Jewish law quite clearly forbids to love a rasha (see rambam end of hilchos rotzeach). If Jesus claimed to be messiah (which I think he did) and Judaism views that as a false claim, then that would make him a "false prophet", and he would probably be considered a rasha, especially if he came to abolish the law. You would have to make a real hard case to prove that loving Jesus is Halachically permitted.

Answer (score 6):

The "yeshu hanotzri" described by the uncensored Talmud is very much a no-goodnik. It is fair game to question which of those passages were intended literally, or referred to which character, or were intended as a way of disparaging people from moving to an emerging religion that was competing with rabbinic Judaism at the time. (The comments may have been more about the religion and its followers than the personality around whom it was founded.)

So it is not violating any of the principles of our faith to say, for instance, "so-and-so was a nice person with good ideas, but we can't accept him as a prophet." Obviously, a certain amount of distance is healthy.

I'd heard a fascinating quote (in a lecture from Rabbi Yaakov Haber) from R' Tzadok HaKohen of Lublin, that once a person reaches the 49th level of holiness, they have to make a decision -- they can either acknowledge that their greatness belongs to G-d alone, or they can decide to be greedy and take the credit for it. Two notable people who did the latter, says R' Tzadok, were Jesus and Shabtai Tzvi.

I'd similarly heard from Rabbi Dr. David Berger, who'd asked Dr. Bernard Lewis, about the Jewish attitudes towards Mohammed during the late medieval "golden age" of Jewish existence in Muslim lands. He said Jews were not in trouble for believing whatever was necessary for them to be Jews (and not Muslims), hence a Jew would not be in trouble for saying "we could not accept his prophecy and redefinition of the law"; he could get in trouble for calling Mohammed insulting names.

Comment: I've heard in the name of Yaavetz (Aharon) that any referrence in the Talmud to Yeshu is not Jesus.

Comment: Was there more than one Yeshu Ha'Notzri? That seems pretty specific to me...

Comment: @SAH Is there more than one Jon the New Yorker?

Comment: @SAH here is one discussion of it http://www.angelfire.com/mt/talmud/jesusnarr.html

Comment: @DoubleAA lol, point taken

Comment: @SAH :) I don't have statistics or anything on frequency of different names in ancient Nazereth or know its population so I can't say for sure. But it's something to consider.

Comment: I think it's yehoshua or something yhswh

Comment: The issue of whether Jesus took the credit for what he did and said is up for debate.  We have to keep in mind that we don't have any eyewitness accounts of his actions and words, and the sources that are available to us are highly questionable.  There is a mountain of evidence that suggests that all the early Christian texts were heavily redacted and revised over the first few centuries of Christianity, and credible scholars generally avoid making claims of authenticity of any given quote or narrative from the NT.

Comment: "So it is not violating..." How does anything your second paragraph have to do with anything in your first paragraph?

Comment: This really does not answer the question. The last paragraph is pretty much irrelevant, the quote from Rav Zaddoq does not tell us what his final state was, but the comparison to SZ sounds pretty bad. More importantly, it says nothing about appropriate attitudes towards Jesus. The first paragraph does not answer the question either. The only answer is in the first sentence of the second paragraph which is totally unsourced, unconvincing and unconnected to the rest of the answer save for a tenuous conjunction.

Comment: @SAH Tosafos HaRosh in Sotah 47a says the gemarra discusses two Yeshus. See [here](http://seforim.blogspot.com/2011/02/new-writings-from-r-kook-and-assorted_22.html) past note 22

Answer (score 5):

Rabbi Aryeh Kaplan wrote a piece called "Behold the man: The real Jesus" found on page 37 of this PDF downloadable [here](https://www.academia.edu/31873088/The_Real_Messiah_Aryeh_Kaplan)

He brings proofs from the new testament showing that Jesus was not the loving, kind person he has been made out to be. Rather he was an unloving, unforgiving, vindictive person who acted with hypocrisy in light of his own teachings.

He focuses for a bit in the opening remarks how impossible it would be for the vicious acts of the crusaders and  the inquisition to have stemmed from the teachings of a good man.

Although he doesn't mention it, this idea seems to based on a passuk in Mishlei that the Talmud in the first chapter of Chulin, 4b brings to prove that all in Achav's camp were bad, and all in Yehoshaphat's camp were good.

משלי כט-יב: מושל מקשיב על דבר שקר כל משרתיו רשעים.

This was all written to combat the common mentality found amongst people, and I quote:  "Many people are fascinated by the person of Jesus. Even when they
find it impossible to accept Christian theology, they still feel that
they can identify with Jesus the person. They see him as someone who
preached love and peace, and whose life embodied the greatest ideals."

According to Rabbi Kaplan, Jesus does not deserve your love or admiration.

Comment: But would it be acceptable?

Comment: Would what be acceptable?

Comment: Love or admiration or appreciating his teachings to any degree.

Comment: I think the questions were asked on the false premise that he was a decent person. This work was written to dispel that belief. But in a more direct sense, the title and opening question 'What attitudes toward Jesus are acceptable for a Jew?' is definitely addressed here. A well know Rabbi has stated his attitude towards Jesus.

Comment: We do not know what would be acceptable, i.e. permissible; only what one rabbi personally felt. We do not even know the range of possible attitudes that that rabbi felt were acceptable.

Comment: Does this link still work?

Comment: @Marcy I changed the link to one that seems to work

Comment: @user6591 Thanks. I found this same link not long after asking. I've read it, and I can't really see how his arguments hold up. A spends a good deal of the page taking advantage of parables. Most ridiculous is his accusation that Jesus didn't care for Gentiles. For example, he not only healed a Roman's servant and told him that he hadn't seen such faith elsewhere, he announced that many from every would enter the Kingdom. The command for the disciples to go only to Israel was in now way permanent, his great commission commanded them to make disciples of every nation

Answer (score 3):

[Here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacob_Emden#Emden-Eybesch.C3.BCtz_controversy) is quote from the wiki entry on Yakov Emden. He saw good in him and his mission.

> In a remarkable apology for Christianity, he wrote that that the original intention of Jesus, and especially of Paul, was to convert only the Gentiles to the Seven Laws of Noah and to let the Jews follow the Mosaic law. Emden praised the ethical teachings of the founder of Christianity, considering them as being beneficial to the Gentiles by removing the prevalence of idolatry and bestowing upon them a "moral doctrine." Emden also suggested that ascetic Christian practices provided additional rectification of the soul in the same way that Judaic commandments do.

Comment: He himself says, "We should consider Christians and Moslems as instruments for the fulfilment of the prophecy that the knowledge of God will one day spread throughout the earth. Whereas the nations before them worshipped idols, denied God's existence, and thus did not recognize God's power or retribution, the rise of Christianity and Islam served to spread among the nations, to the furthest ends of the earth, the knowledge that there is One God who rules the world, who rewards and punishes and reveals Himself to man." (from the same wiki article)

Comment: @Sarah there is an argument amongst the Rabbis if Christianity is considered idol worship for nonjews. All agree it is idol worship for Jews. But even Maimonides who believed it is actual idol worship even for nonjews, saw in it a general move towards the right direction away from the disgusting practices of ancient idol worshippers. It's a tough multifaceted discussion.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure there is any proof that Jesus ever existed. the only documents that reference him directly are not first hand historical texts. these include the christian bible and Josephus. as far as the talmud that allegedly references Jesus these cannot refer to the Jesus of christianity as they either lived in a different location or different century. In my opinion the correct Jewish view of Jesus is a fairy tale created by wicked people to create a new religion. This new religion was then capitalized upon by the Roman government as a means of controlling the population and territorial expansion. As far as the Jewish view of christianity for non Jews in modern times. The positive are a set of morals to live by and that this introduced to the world the idea of mashiach and when mashiach comes goyim will realize they had the wrong person and the rest of false beliefs around mashiach were wrong as well.

Comment: I recall seeing a statement that the reference to *that person* in Josephus was actually added by a Christian writer centuries later so it would not be valid. The only reference would be in the writings of those believers, none of which were at that time.

Comment: it certainly does answer the question. he wasn't a real person and that's how we should view him.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer to this question should pivot on the point of "may we jews love j___?"

Was j___ a jew? If yes, and most all of the historic information points to yes, that born of a jewess, he was a jew, so then, as part of the tribe, we should treat him like we treat jews.

Since he was a jew then there can be some fences about what is possible to say about this deceased person.

It has been discussed on MY so many other aspects of the followers of j___ and whether jews are allowed to paricipate in any of those things.
For this question its not the time to make those points.

What are the limits of what we could say if deceased j____ was a heretic? Should we treat him any differently than any other deceased jew? This raises other questions, too broad and not quite on the topic that covers whether we are in any way obligated to love j____.

Comment: The question wasn't exactly "should we", but "may we". || Actually the question of whether he was a Jew is mostly irrelevant. There are different categories of Jews, and not all deserve, in the OP's words "reverence and love".

Comment: `Since he was a jew then there can be some fences about what is possible to say about this deceased person.` At most it is forbidden to say negative untrue things about the dead. That doesn't mean that it is forbidden to say the negative truth. It is likely irrelevant given other rules that govern speech even among the living, allowing publicly known information to be discussed, for example. || Furthermore, the question wasn't what one may say, but what attitudes are appropriate.

Comment: @mevaqesh , yes a heratic or non jew might only deserve a slightly different attitude? What do you think it would be, I agree as you say "negative truth" saying about dead people, even jews, is possibly not forbidden. But that kind of makes the question moot, no? or is it possible to love and reverence a heritic?

Comment: @mevaqesh I agree, not all deserve rverence and love. I think that is what I was trying to say, it was convoluted